# Recursive joinload object in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

today I ran into such a problem, it is required to load a sqlalchemy tree object with configured links for rendering. But I do not know the depth of the object, it can change. Actually, the question is whether I can somehow load all the connections in an object and its children and their children, etc. with one request.

I have experimented with various loading methods, but none of them helped, perhaps someone has encountered this problem

Answer (score 0):

The documentation goes into a little bit of this in the [Adjancency List section](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/self_referential.html#adjacency-list-relationships).  You are limited to setting a fixed depth with adjancy lists as far as I know.

If you are inserting a lot I would avoid nested sets and maybe even materialized paths.

I have sort of side stepped this in one project by grouping subtrees and using the group's id to get that subtree.  For example if you have a tree of nodes with arbitrary nesting that make up an html page then each page has its own id and you just store that with every node and get them all at once (usually <50).  This doesn't always work but sometimes it helps to sidestep the problem.

There are examples for both the alternatives.  They are pretty cool but I still think most of the time it is more difficult to maintain and you have to be careful all the time to not do something horribly slow:

[materialized_paths](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/_modules/examples/materialized_paths/materialized_paths.html)

[nested_sets](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/_modules/examples/nested_sets/nested_sets.html)